# Difference in how LINQ to Entities and LINQ to Objects handle casts

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have recently joined a project where a `Sort` method was conditionally passing in a lambda expression to a LINQ query to define which property should be sorted on. The problem was that the lambda expression was being passed in a `Func<TEntity, Object`> and not in an `Expression<Func<TEntity, Object>>` so that the sorting was taking place in memory and not on the database (because the overload of `OrderBy` that takes an `IEnumerable` is called). This is the version in `SortWithDelegate` (see below).

When I use an `Expression<Func<TEntity, Object>>` (see `SortWithExpression` below) then, when a string property is passed in the `orderBy` parameter, the ordering is done correctly in the database. However, when I try to sort on an integer (or datetime) using `Expression<Func<TEntity, Object>>` I get the following error:

`Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.`

To avoid this I have to wrap the integer or datetime field to be sorted on inside an anonymous type like so: `orderByFunc = sl => new {sl.ParentUnit.Id};`. I understand I need to do this as the return type of the `Func` is `Object`. However, what I do not understand is why I need to do this when working with the LINQ to Entities provider but not the LINQ to Objects provider?

```
void Main()
{
    var _context = new MyContext();

    string sortProperty = "Id";
    bool sortAscending = false;


    IQueryable<Qualification> qualifications = _context.Qualifications.Include(q => q.ParentUnit);

    qualifications = SortWithExpression(sortProperty, sortAscending, qualifications);

    qualifications.Dump();

}

private static IQueryable<Qualification> SortWithDelegate(string orderBy, bool sortAscending, IQueryable<Qualification> qualificationsQuery)
{
    Func<Qualification, Object> orderByFunc;

    switch (orderBy)
    {
        case "Name":
            orderByFunc = sl => sl.Name;
            break;
        case "ParentUnit":
            orderByFunc = sl => sl.ParentUnit.Name;
            break;
        case "Id":
            orderByFunc = sl => sl.ParentUnit.Id;
            break;
        case "Created":
            orderByFunc = sl => sl.Created;
            break;
        default:
            orderByFunc = sl => sl.Name;
            break;
    }

    qualificationsQuery = sortAscending
        ? qualificationsQuery.OrderBy(orderByFunc).AsQueryable()
            : qualificationsQuery.OrderByDescending(orderByFunc).AsQueryable();

    return qualificationsQuery;
}

private static IQueryable<Qualification> SortWithExpression(string orderBy, bool sortAscending, IQueryable<Qualification> qualificationsQuery)
{
    Expression<Func<Qualification, Object>> orderByFunc;

    switch (orderBy)
    {
        case "Name":
            orderByFunc = sl => sl.Name;
            break;
        case "ParentUnit":
            orderByFunc = sl => sl.ParentUnit.Name;
            break;
        case "Id":
            orderByFunc = sl => new {sl.ParentUnit.Id};
            break;
        case "Created":
            orderByFunc = sl => new {sl.Created};
            break;
        default:
            orderByFunc = sl => sl.Name;
            break;
    }

    qualificationsQuery = sortAscending
        ? qualificationsQuery.OrderBy(orderByFunc)
            : qualificationsQuery.OrderByDescending(orderByFunc);

    return qualificationsQuery;
}
```

**Added**

Just thought I'd add my own solution to this problem. To avoid boxing `int` and `datetime` I've created a generic extension method on `IQueryable<T>` to which I pass in the lambda expression to indicate the sort field and a boolean indicating whether the sort order should be ascending or not:

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> query, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> func, bool sortAscending)
    {
        return sortAscending ?
            query.OrderBy(func) :
                query.OrderByDescending(func);
    }

    private static IQueryable<Qualification> Sort(string orderBy, bool sortAscending, IQueryable<Qualification> qualificationsQuery)
    {
        switch (orderBy)
        {
            case "Name":
                return qualificationsQuery.OrderBy(sl => sl.Name, sortAscending);
            case "ParentUnit":
                return qualificationsQuery.OrderBy(s1 => s1.ParentUnit.Name, sortAscending);
            default:
                return qualificationsQuery.OrderBy(sl => sl.Name, sortAscending);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why not do a google search on the error and it will yield many examples as to what you can do to correct this issue you are facing..

Comment: I can work around this issue. The point of my question was to inquire why there is a difference in how LINQ-to-Entities and LINQ-to-Objects deal with types in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression trees as their name implies are expression about doing something.you can visit the expressions and interpret them to your own business or like lambda expressions you can compile them and invoke as a delegate.

When you pass the expression to orderby method in Linq to Entities, it will be visited by Linq to Entities and in your case that "Int32 to Object" exception will be generated because the way it is interpreted as a MemberInfo that turn into a column name for the database query. But when you use it as a Func delegate, it can not be translated and it will be invoked as a delegate for comparison in orderby method's sort algorithm.

Comment: "because the way it is interpreted as a MemberInfo that turn into a column name for the database query" - this is what I was looking for. Thanks!